# Getting Spark 1.5 to run on mac local

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython

I downloaded the prebuilt spark for hadoop 2.4 and I'm getting the following error when I try to fire up a SparkContext in python:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
```

The following code should be correct:

```
import sys, os
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = '/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/'
sys.path.insert(0, '/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.4/python/')
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/'
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext('local[2]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my issue was that the default JDK on my mac is Java 1.6 and Spark 1.5 dropped support for Java 1.6 ([reference](http://search-hadoop.com/m/q3RTtojAyW1dabFk)). I upgraded to Java 1.8 with the [installer from oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), and it fixed the problem.